# Postgres Select for the exact match ovet set of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get best match out of following data set out of postgresSQL.

Data set example: (Following data set belongs to the parents OR I would say that I am keeping dynamic Parent properties in the table called tbl_parent_meta_data)

```
Filters: Brand=BMW, Wheels=17 & Model=B2017
```

Depending on above filters, SQL should return parentId only matches the filters, ie: 9080 & 9082

```
+----+----------+-------------+---------------+
| Id | AdId     | MetaDataKey | MetaDataValue |
+----+----------+-------------+---------------+
|  1 |     9080 | Brand       | BMW           |
|  2 |     9080 | Wheels      | 17            |
|  3 |     9080 | Model       | B2017         |
|  4 |     9081 | Brand       | BMW           |
|  5 |     9081 | Wheels      | 18            |
|  6 |     9081 | Model       | B2016         |
|  7 |     9082 | Brand       | Audi          |
|  8 |     9082 | Wheels      | 19            |
|  9 |     9081 | Model       | A2016         |
| 10 |     9082 | Brand       | BMW           |
| 11 |     9082 | Wheels      | 17            |
| 12 |     9082 | Model       | B2017         |
+----+----------+-------------+---------------+
```

Query I used: This worked for me, I need alternatives.

```
SELECT axd.ad_id adId
FROM ads_extradata axd
LEFT JOIN ads a on a.id = axd.ad_id
LEFT JOIN categories_translations ct ON ct.id = a.category_translation_id
LEFT JOIN categories_meta_data cmd ON cmd.id = axd.category_metadata_id
LEFT JOIN languages l ON l.id = ct.language_id
WHERE cmd.deleted = false AND ct.deleted = false AND a.deleted = false     
AND axd.deleted = false
AND  a.category_translation_id = '" . $categoryTranslation->getId() . "'
GROUP BY axd.ad_id
HAVING SUM(
CASE 'Brand' WHEN axd.extra_value::text THEN 10 ELSE 0 END +
CASE 'Wheels' WHEN axd.extra_value::text THEN 10 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE 'Model' WHEN axd.extra_value::text THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) >= 30
```

Comment: What query have you tried?

Comment: Thanks Radu, I updated the question with query I used, that worked fine. But loking for alternatives

Answer (score 1):

Assume that  you could extract your filter and apply to your query

Then you could do

```
SELECT parentid
FROM table_name
WHERE (metadatakey, metadatavalue) IN (
        ('Brand', 'BMW'), 
        ('Wheels', '17'), 
        ('Model', 'B2017') 
    )
GROUP BY parentid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT metadatakey) = 3; --number of equality filter
--If you don't have duplicate (metadatakey, metadatavalue) for each 
--    parentid then use COUNT(*) instead
```

Comment: The `where` clause can be simplified to `where (metadatakey, metadatavalue ) in ( ('Brand', 'BMW'), ('Wheels', '17'), ('Model', 'B2017'))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will test it today, and get back to you.